# Azure DevOps CI-CD pipeline for Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure-devops, azure-data-factory, cicd

I have created a CI-CD pipeline to deploy pipelines from my development data factory to production data factory and it works perfect for the first run. However, when a change is made in the dev, for example,

> renamed pipeline1 to pipeline001

the production data factory has a pipeline by the name pipeline001 and also pipeline1, both of which are the same. The issues persists for any kind of change and not just restricted to renaming.
I checked the json templates, which was found ok.
Any help?

Comment: Are you deploying with ARM templates? Depending on the types of changes, the `Incremental` deployment mode will _add_ to your existing resources.

Comment: @joelforsyth I tried that and now after the release pipeline was run, all my resources inside the resource group has been deleted.

Comment: Yes, the `Complete` mode will delete everything in the resource group that isn't included in the ARM per the documentation

Comment: @joelforsyth I tried setting up fresh datafactory with no pipelines inside it and executed the released. The release worked fine but the resources weren't deployed to my factory (this was in "complete" deployment mode). Shouldn't the resources have been replicated at the target if the target was empty?

Comment: Complete deployment mode says that all resources for that resource group are included in that ARM template. Are you including all of the Data Factory resources in your ARM template? In other words, are the things you're missing in the Data Factory included in the ARM?